# Cannot find hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

My workstation used to have a traditional hard drive for data storage. However one day the disk is disappeared in Ubuntu but it can be seen in Windows. In the Disk manager, there is a present of the disk as sdb2 but the partitions inside cannot be written. It cannot even read the format, see the picture from this link, [Disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVxWm.png). When USB is plug-in, it cannot be auto mounted and needs to be manually mount. However the other SSD drives are all fine.

Also the apt upgrade is not working at the same time. An message is shown: "**E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem**"

This problem has been here for few weeks but I cannot find any post which has a solution to it. Could someone help me please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please only ask one question at the time ... for the apt problem, try to do as the error message says.

Comment: For the partition, try to mount it, and unmount it correctly from windows. If you want to be able just to shut down windows without unmounting the disks first, disable fastboot and hibernation in Windows.